# BIRT: How do I include a JAR in the report?

Tags: jar, include, birt

In the BIRT book "[Integrating and Extending BIRT](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321443853)" (2nd edition, p. 296), I've found this little piece of text:

> BIRT searches locations for external classes in the order shown in the following list:
>
> [...]
>
> - JAR files that are included in the report design.

How do I include a JAR file in the report design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the report's properties (lower-right of the IDE) you can look down the list of available sub-groups and find "Resources".  Inside this group you can specify JARS that are to be available to the report at run-time.

Comment: Shouldn't that be the Property Editor tab, rather than the Properties tab? (It might be different in different versions - I don't know.)

Comment: When I click "add", I offers a folder "Shared Resources". Where is that folder on disk?

Comment: How are you deploying your reports?  To a standard J2EE web server or an Actuate iServer?  The two deployments offer different options so I want to clarify.

Comment: I need the JAR in the report designer and on a J2EE web server (tomcat) where I run the viewerservlet.